# Extract javascript-generated links with selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, ads

I'm trying to extract ads from webpages. I'm using iplocation's page as my starting page. Iplocation serves ads from double-click(adsense). For now I'm focusing only on ads outside iframes, of the form

`<a href="...", ...>
<img src="...", ...>
</a>`

First step is to get all anchor tags and then I'll check href attribute of those anchor tags. But I'm not getting these javascript-generated anchor tags in my selenium code. I have tried both implicit wait and explicit wait, but no success. I've also explored some of the solutions given on stack-overflow for waiting to page to be loaded, but nothing seems to work. I want to get link of doubleclick among the list of anchor tags. Here is the code:

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 String baseUrl = "http://iplocation.net/";
 driver.get(baseUrl);

 List<WebElement> allAnchorTags= driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
 System.out.println("Number of anchor tags = "+allAnchorTags.size());

 for(Element a : doc.getElementsByTag("a")){
     String url = a.attr("abs:href");
     System.out.println(url);
 }
```

Edit1: Example of javascript-generated anchor tags. Data of one of the ads shown, taken from iplocation.net

```
<a data-original-click-url="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=C6VDnU-5yV-_8EZO_Wqq9rdAPvYOC_kTVrt2I_wLFkpOWiwUQASDjheAdYMvctAWgAYvv1b4DyAECqAMByAPBBKoEe0_Qlt9if5TWbxdiiMYNqHQfoxw4kBBibtZIqaosjVqUCjcPPca0lHl4k_GaLNt1_cXekFO1tH7ythmHWyV2u34pE9VHAIHEEl-IuzRea2pSXLE_2vVe_bg982jp-jkFG8K0q-WHIETCWTTUt0LbOS4A-GYzCuqdyf5S7ogGAaAGAoAH3ZCqQagHpr4b2AcB&amp;num=1&amp;cid=CAASEuRofHi4jyWW3saxgIxOgVIsBQ&amp;sig=AOD64_14Fv-B2-gzVrNHqJNoh_Q4tfkL9A&amp;client=ca-pub-1026064395378929&amp;adurl=https://semanticscholar.org" id="aw0" target="_top" href="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=C6VDnU-5yV-_8EZO_Wqq9rdAPvYOC_kTVrt2I_wLFkpOWiwUQASDjheAdYMvctAWgAYvv1b4DyAECqAMByAPBBKoEe0_Qlt9if5TWbxdiiMYNqHQfoxw4kBBibtZIqaosjVqUCjcPPca0lHl4k_GaLNt1_cXekFO1tH7ythmHWyV2u34pE9VHAIHEEl-IuzRea2pSXLE_2vVe_bg982jp-jkFG8K0q-WHIETCWTTUt0LbOS4A-GYzCuqdyf5S7ogGAaAGAoAH3ZCqQagHpr4b2AcB&amp;num=1&amp;cid=CAASEuRofHi4jyWW3saxgIxOgVIsBQ&amp;sig=AOD64_14Fv-B2-gzVrNHqJNoh_Q4tfkL9A&amp;client=ca-pub-1026064395378929&amp;nm=1&amp;mb=2&amp;bg=!RkWlRV1EI6hvpP6naIMCAAAAR1IAAAA6mQE0TMakESu8sZGPa3bBy_OqpXrYwIAq6s1kayeXAKDeUXdm9RPIzlFXaGuBM1rGtEmhztZlKhdfiJQpbiXILcVlbzrbvG-DijStEsCGTTlUX-Nb9c_qCHE5b9SQx2a_6-AxumGJUHj3Mlf2nv8dG-Z93YyX4yblF6L5XInRxaqwsTpVhNebQdUmoer7uDSSik4fI48VOgk1_PungBhrjkLSbWJKGV6gFH7PqyrAC5pZ-WDYS7g_y7EmFz_DIBtKotP0gjz2CucJWn93h01HQQDBKSNNgj-pERxb1jWIP14t9lBrlRjuez8n0xtlbQyvDRHt7VKtQ8d4pfBNAb2b80mJu6D2KuwpZndHqaZ8GO-a48qXXily5FELFK-uhNc6krqgzxcUgeGAjZAC_-EUVIm8WN1pQcc&amp;adurl=https://semanticscholar.org"><img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/8383265107738210087" alt="" class="img_ad" onload="" width="336" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML for an example of the javascript-generated anchor tags that you are referring to?

Comment: @JeffC Added. These are the anchor tags which are dynamically generated and missing from the list.

Comment: I'm looking at the site right now and the one `A` tag I see with `data-original-click-url` as an attribute is inside an `IFRAME`. That's one reason why you wouldn't see them with the code you have. You would need to add an iteration through all the `IFRAME`s also looking for `A` tags.

Comment: As I mentioned, for now, I'm focusing on ads outside iframes. Out of 3 ads on website, at most 1 is in an iframe, others are not. I want to capture those. And it's true for any website. I'm not able to do this on any website. If you can make a case for any website, that would be fine.

Comment: My point is that I don't think you are missing any `A` tags outside of the `IFRAME`s. If you launch the page and have Selenium count the `A` tags and then leave the browser window up and type `document.getElementsByTagName("a").length` in the browser console, the counts are the same. I have done this several times and the counts are always the same. The example tag you provided was inside an `IFRAME` so wouldn't be counted and, as you said, you are ignoring them for now.

Comment: You are right. And that's surprising. But the problem is I want to capture those ads. I should probably try on some different websites using this comparison.